# How to refresh text from a text file on a timer

Tags: c#

I need to know how to refresh the text on a timer **I do not want it to detect when change happens**
I would also like to have the ability to write to it.

My code :

```cs
Console.Clear();
string filepath = @"StrWorkPath\Chat.log";

List<string> lines = File.ReadAllLines(filepath).ToList();
foreach (string line in lines)
{
    Console.WriteLine(line);
}
Console.Write("");
string chat;
chat = Console.ReadLine();
lines.Add(chat);
File.WriteAllLines(filepath, lines);
```

Also I am new to c# so don't get mad over my terrible code.

Comment: So you want to be able to type text to the console while some text is being outputted on the screen?

Answer (score -1):

There are two general purpose timers in .NET:

#### [System.Threading.Timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.timer)

This class enables you to continuously call a delegate at specified time intervals. You can also use this class to schedule a single call to a delegate in a specified time interval. The delegate is executed on a [ThreadPool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool) thread.

Example:

```cs
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Program
{
    private static Timer timer;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        timer = new Timer(
            callback: new TimerCallback(TimerTask),
            state: /* your state object here */,
            dueTime: 1000,
            period: 2000);

        Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:HH:mm:ss.fff}: done.");
    }

    private static void TimerTask(object timerState)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:HH:mm:ss.fff}: starting a new callback.");
        //you can cast timerState to it's concrete type here
    }
}
```

#### [System.Timers.Timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer)

Another timer that can be used in a multithreaded environment is System.Timers.Timer that by default raises an event on a ThreadPool thread.

When you create a System.Timers.Timer object, you may specify the time interval in which to raise an Elapsed event. Use the Enabled property to indicate if a timer should raise an Elapsed event. If you need an Elapsed event to be raised only once after the specified interval has elapsed, set the AutoReset to false. The default value of the AutoReset property is true, which means that an Elapsed event is raised regularly at the interval defined by the Interval property.

You can start reading from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/timers

Comment: Please provide a concrete solution or explanation, providing links-only answer is bad, especially if the link is broken in the future.

Comment: @TsahiAsher, adding a summary or quotes from link is much better, exactly as you did. By the way, I am not the down-voter :), I don't like down-voting, I appreciate any kind of trying to help. However, your code will not work as the asker described? Because he will not able to enter new text.

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin how do you mean? his code should go to the TimerTask callback.